# How to show the variable text in Kivy interface

Tags: python, kivy, kivymd

I am trying to use Kivy to create an interface. But when I try to show the text of a variable (result) it doesn't show it. Here the code:

```
from kivymd.app import MDApp
from kivy.lang import Builder
from covid import Covid


covid = Covid(source='worldometers')
data = covid.get_status_by_country_name('Italy')
for k in data:
    result = k+str(data[k])

KV = '''
Screen: 
    Label:
        text: result
        pos_hint: {'center_x': 0.5, 'center_y': 0.5}
    
'''

class MainApp(MDApp):
    def build(self):
        self.title = "Covid"
        self.theme_cls.theme_style = "Dark"  # Light
        self.theme_cls.primary_palette = "Red"
        return Builder.load_string(KV)

MainApp().run()
```

I'm sorry for my english but I'm Italian then I'm not very good.

Comment: Without a [mcve] your question is difficult to answer. Generally, two ways to accomplish it are to either add code after you get `result` to set the `text` property of the `MDRectangleFlatButton` or to create a `StringProperty` somewhere and reference that in your `kv`.

Comment: I added all the code, now it's ok?

Answer (score 0):

Good day. Kivy is an App framework. You need to create an entire [App class](https://kivy.org/doc/stable/api-kivy.app.html) and build your logic into the App.

I recommend that after you create the `App` class, instantiate it, run it,  then run your logic code in your App.

kv script:

```
Screen:
    MDRectangleButton:
        on_release: app.calculate_result_callback
```

In Python:

```
import .......

data = covid.get_status_by_country_name('Italy')
covid = Covid(source='worldometers')
def calculate_result():
    result = ""
    for k in data:
        result += k+str(data[k])
    return result

class MyApp(App):
    def calculate_result_callback(self, instance, *a):
        result = calculate_result()
        instance.text = result
```